# To grep lines from file ending with backslash

Tags: perl, csh

I have a file,named FILE with backslashes in end in some lines. like

```
 a
sbajcb
ksajcnx \
cjscnk\
snk
sknds\
```

When i am using this command  `grep -G '\\$' FILE` , i am getting the results.

But when i am executing this in Perl, i am not getting the results.

My code is

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
my $runme=$ARGV[0];
if(-e $runme) {
my $all_lines = `grep -G '\\\$' $runme`;
print $all_lines;
}
```

Whats wrong in my code? , i tried using `'\\$'` , still didn't get the result.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get anything back from the `qx//`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl already strips one layer of quoting, so the actual command that is executed becomes

```
grep -G '\$' $runme
```

To solve this, double the backslashes again, leaving one for the $:

```
my $all_lines = `grep -G '\\\\\$' $runme`;
```

Of course you could reimplement the `grep` directly in perl:

```
open my $fh, "<", $runme or die "Cannot open '$runme': $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/\\$/) {
        print $_;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to close $fh afterwards, either by letting it go out of scope or an explicit `close $fh`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your filename is already in `@ARGV`, there is no need to shell out to achieve this. Implementing it in Perl saves the time needed to start a shell and is cross-platform.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

exit unless -e $ARGV[0];

# <> will return records from the files
# named in @ARGV
while (<>) {
  print if /\\$/;
}
```